# Where is the config file for Portal 2 located on OSX?

Tags: portal-2, macos, source-engine

I am having trouble finding the config.cfg config file for the Source engine on OSX.  It isn't in an obvious place in the package.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in `SteamApps/common/portal 2/portal2/cfg/config.cfg`.

[Source](http://tehparadox.com/forum/f18/portal-2-lan-*tutorial-2111450/) (The Portal 2 folder should be under common like all recent Valve games, if it's not, try `SteamApps/yourusername/portal 2`)

Comment: It looks like you're describing a Windows path, but I'll take a look later.

Comment: Once you get into the SteamApps directory, the directory layout is the same in both OSes for Steam games.

Comment: Found it in two locations (literally find / -iname config.cfg):

Local: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/portal 2/portal2/cfg/config.cfg

To connecting clients?: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/87376964/620/remote/cfg/config.cfg

Not sure why I didn't think about using find before!  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @mbrownnyc You can just put in a tilde for the home directory. `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/portal 2/portal2/cfg/config.cfg` and `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/87376964/620/remote/cfg/config.cfg`.